# C++ Properties with setter and getter

Tags: c++

Hi im new to C++ for arduino and i know properties from many other languages.

In C# I can write Properties with setter and getter like this:

```
public int foo
{
  get
  {
    return bar;
  }
  set
  {
    bar = value;
  }
}
```

Is something like this possible in C++?
I cant find a fancy solution which i can split into header and source files. :/

Comment: With a property the implementation of a conceptual “value” as a data member or computation can be changed at will without affecting the usage notation. Bertrand Meyer called that the **[uniform access principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_access_principle)**. But simple accessor and modifier functions can also support the uniform access principle, so it's not an advantage of properties as such; rather, it would be a dis-advantage if properties didn't also support the principle. So, properties that cannot be detected as such by tools, seem to have negative utility. In C++.

Comment: That said, you can implement properties as simple directly exposed member variables with custom assignment and conversion operator. It has some overhead. And since properties in C++ appear to have negative utility, it doesn't make sense other than maybe aesthetically.

Answer (score 4):

**C++ doesnt have C#-style-like properties.**

but you can have a setter and getter function declared in header and then define it in source files.

example:

```
///in header file
class Test
{
    public:
         int getX();
         void setX(int newX);
    private:
         int x;
}

//in source file

int Test::getX()
{
     return x;
}

void Test::setX(int newX)
{
      x = newX;
}
```

**EDIT:**

when working with header files you should put a header guards on it.

read about this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Answer (score 2):

Writing wrapping template class will help you.
In the class, by overloading some special functions, you can chase access to underlying object.

```
template <class T, class Object, T(Object::*real_getter)(), T(Object::*real_setter)(T const &)> 
class RWProperty 
{ 
private:
    Object * my_object;
public:
    RWProperty() : my_object(0) {}
    RWProperty(Object * me = 0) : my_object(me) {}
    void operator()(Object * obj) { my_object = obj; }
    T operator()() const { return (my_object->*real_getter)(); }
    T operator()(T const & value) { return (my_object->*real_setter)(value); }
    T get() const { return (my_object->*real_getter)(); }
    T set(T const & value) { return (my_object->*real_setter)(value); }
    operator T() const { return (my_object->*real_getter)(); }
    T operator=(T const & value) { return (my_object->*real_setter)(value); }
    typedef T value_type;
};

//Use case from here.
#include <iostream>

struct Widget
{
private:
    int value_;
    int get(void) { std::cout << "Real getter called." << std::endl; return value_; }
    int set(const int& _value) {  std::cout << "Real setter called." << std::endl; return value_ = _value; }
public:
    RWProperty<int, Widget, &get, &set> value;
    Widget(void):value(this){}
};


int main(void)
{
    Widget w;
    w.value = 31337; //Call Widget::set(Called real setter in RWProperty) indirectly.
    std::cout << w.value; //Call Widget::get(Called real getter in RWProperty)
}
```

You should also read "C++ Properties - a Library Solution" for another information.
In the paper, several type of property classes, typed by its access authority, are introduced.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Foo
{
public:
    int get()
    {
        return bar;
    }

    void set( int new_bar )
    {
        bar = new_bar;
    }

private:
    int bar;
};
```

This will give you a class name Foo. This class has a private member, bar. You can set the value of bar through the set() method, and you can get the value of bar via the set() method.

Answer (score 0):

Like C# it is not possible same way but you can try some thing like below.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void bar(int val){ _bar=val;}
    int bar(){ return  _bar;}

private:
    int _bar;
};
```